# Modifying pixels by implicit equation

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, image-processing, implicit

## edit:

In short way:
I have three pictures: reference image, and two others. The reference image is used for adjust the other two to proper values. - this part should be ok.
Then I subtract the other two pictures(arrays) from each other and I receive some array in which my pixels are hidden - also done
and now the tricky part:

[image]

this is my equation which I would like to solve in each pixel separately and my result should be "h" in a new array which I will export to excel
Thanks a lot for help.

```
import scipy
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from scipy.optimize import fsolve                    


P0 = Image.open('3kanaly0.tif')                                                               
m = scipy.misc.imread("3kanaly0.tif")
P0 = m[:,:,0]
print(P0)

P0_T = np.array(P0)/4

#1image
m = scipy.misc.imread("3.tif")
P1 = m[:,:,0]
print(P1)

P1_T = np.array(P1)/4                               
print(P1_T.shape)
print("P1_T (z)",type(P1_T))
print(P1_T)


#adjust
Texp = input()
Texp = int(Texp)

print("Start beta")
def beta(Texp,Tcal = 20):
    return Texp/Tcal
b = beta(Texp)
print("beta :", b)
print(" beta")

print("Start alfa")
def alfa(A,B,C,D,b):
    return A*b**3+B*b**2+C*b+D
wynik_alfa = alfa(0.0097,-0.08,-0.038,1.016,b)
print("alfa i:",wynik_alfa)
print(" alfa")

#
Tcal = 20
a = -10.978
b = 22.76
c = -19.317
d = 8.4634
Temp_T =  Tcal*(a*(wynik_alfa*P1_T/P0_T)**3+b*(wynik_alfa*P1_T/P0_T)**2+c*wynik_alfa*P1_T/P0_T+d)




#2image
m = scipy.misc.imread("3kanaly2.tif")
P2 = m[:,:,0]

Temp_T2 =  Tcal*(a*(wynik_alfa*P2_T/P0_T)**3+b*(wynik_alfa*P2_T/P0_T)**2+c*wynik_alfa*P2_T/P0_T+d)




r = np.subtract(Temp_T,Temp_T2)



a = 20
k = 400
Tpow = 80.0
ro = 8920
cp = 384
t = 2

print(type(k))
print(type(Tpow))
print(type(ro))
print(type(cp))
print(type(t))
print(type(P1_T))
print(type(r))


for i in range(len(Temp_T)):
    for j in range(len(Temp_T2[0])):
        fsolve((r[i][j] + (Tpow -Temp_T[i][j])*(1-exp(h**2)*exp(a*t/k**2)*h*(a**0.5*t**0.5)/k)))
```

Comment: Where is P0_T defined?

Comment: Updated P0_T :)

Comment: I'll assume that `P2_T = np.array(P2)/4`? 'h' is not defined but it is used in fsolve. What should 'h' be?

Comment: I don't think that's a valid use of `fsolve`; its first argument should be a function, not an evaluated value, and fsolve appears to be missing its second argument, nor is its return value used (which holds the solution). Which makes me think you're not doing what you think you are doing in the first place.

Comment: P2_T= np.array(P2)/4 because I have 14bit in my camera and in python I use 16bit.
The h is my unknown - that is a reason why I didn't define it.
I'm not IT specialist - this is my first code.

Comment: If you know other way instead of using fsolve i'm very open-minded :)

Answer (score 0):

Your post is slightly ambiguous, but I will try to help you further regardless. I am not feeling very confident about the 'solvability' of your problem as stated above, because the two ways I interpret your writings lead to two different problems. From what I understand, you are trying to solve the following problem:

1) `R = A(h)*P1`

Where A is the operator that connects the image `P1` to the residual `R=P1-P2`, which depends on a number of variables (a, k, t) that you have given values, and in addition, it depends on the quantity `h` that you would like to find.

If this is true, there are two options. First, if `h` is independent for each pixel - so what you are after is N values of h - your problem is essentially the following:

2) `R[i][j] = A(h)[i][j] * P1[i][j]`

N being the number of pixels. Note that 2) is NOT a matrix equation, the multiplication here is element-wise rather than a matrix multiplication. So what we are looking at here is N unrelated equations. From this, it follows you should not use a matrix solving technique to find the solution. If you are not able to rewrite 2) such that it is explicit (i.e. h = ... ), you will not be able to solve for h. If you cannot write the solution for your equation using mathematics, you will not be able to write a program that solves it.

The second option is that you are looking for a single value of `h`. In this case, the problem you are trying to solve is a matrix-vector equation that roughly takes the following form:

3) `R[:] = A(h)P1[:]`

where R and P1 have been reorganised to vectors of length N, and A is an N-by-N matrix of some form (sparse or dense). In this case, we cannot solve the problem because the matrix A is not unique; you have N equations and N^2 unknowns. It is possible that multiple values of h lead to a solution, or alternatively, that the problem can only be solved in a least-squares sense.

If the problem you are trying to solve is different from the two I wrote above, please try to write down the problem you are trying to solve in a mathematical way, I think that will be very helpful in finding a solution (if it exists).

Comment: I updated what is my problem (clearly), so if you would be so kind and check it, I'd be so glad.
Thanks a lot for your help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I think the solution of BHawk should work here. I do not know how large the images will be that you will be importing, but it might be good to try it on a small excerpt of the images first. For instance, let `i` and `j` run from 1 to 5 in your last lines of code, and time how long it takes (e.g. using the timeit module). You will be able to get a feel for how long the entire procedure will take, and you can substitute the values you get out for `h` back into your equation and check for correctness yourself :-).

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I see, you are trying to solve for h using fsolve. Fsolve takes a function as it's initial argument and an initial guess of the missing value as the second argument. So you need to define your equation as a function:

```
def equation(h):
  return r[i][j] + (Tpow -P1_T[i][j])*(1-exp(h**2)*exp(a*t/k**2)*h*(a**0.5*t**0.5)/k)
```

then pass that function to fsolve, along with an initial guess for h (5 in this case):

```
h_vals = np.zeros_like(P0_T)
for i in range(len(P1_T)):
    print(i)
    for j in range(len(P1_T[0])):
        a = fsolve(equation,5)
        h_vals[i][j] = a
```

Depending on your image this may take a long time to compute.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I really appreciate it.
I updated what is my problem (clearly), so if you would be so kind and check if your previous code is coherent with that, I'd be very glad
(I suppose that the code is correct to my expectation but I'm not an expert)